# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax in phpMyadmin

Tags: sql, mariadb

I built the following Query, for MySQL, on Maria Db, phpMyAdmin Ver: 4.8.3

Database server

```
Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.1.36-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version: 10
```

Web server

```
Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0i PHP/7.2.10
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
PHP version: 7.2.10
```

SQL

```
SELECT tblhoadon.MaHoaDon, 
       tblkhachhang.HoVaTen, 
       tblphongtro.MaSoPhong, 
       tblphongtro.GiaThue, 
       tbldichvu.MaDichVu, 
       tblchitietdv.TenChiPhi, 
       tblchitietdv.ThanhTien, 
       tblhoadon.TongTien 
FROM tblhoadon, 
     tblphongtro,
     tbldichvu,
     tblchitietdv 
WHERE tblhoadon.MaKhachHang = tblkhachhang.MaKhachHang, 
      tblhoadon.MaSoPhong   = tblphongtro.MaSoPhong,
      tblhoadon.MaDichVu    = tbldichvu.MaDichVu,
      tbldichvu.MaDichVu    = tblchitietdv.MaDichVu LIKE 10040001
```

Report error

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near ' tblhoadon.MaSoPhong = tblphongtro.MaSoPhong, tblhoadon.MaDichVu
> = tbldichvu.MaD' at line 1

Can you help me fix syntax error?

Comment: The `LIKE 10040001` is at an odd place, and you have to use `AND` instead of commas in your `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Hint:  `AND`, probably, maybe `OR`.

Comment: **HINT** with proper indentation, it is much easier to figure out what is going on in the query.

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just have a series of conditions. You need some logical operator between them, such as `and` or `or`. 
Additionally, the last condition has several issues:

1. like` should take a string argument, not a number
2. You can't chain equalities like that, you should create two conditions with a logical `and` operator between them.
3. While it's not strictly wrong to use `like` without a wildcard, it's a bit pointless, and you can just use an `=` condition:

```
SELECT tblhoadon.MaHoaDon, 
       tblkhachhang.HoVaTen, 
       tblphongtro.MaSoPhong, 
       tblphongtro.GiaThue, 
       tbldichvu.MaDichVu, 
       tblchitietdv.TenChiPhi, 
       tblchitietdv.ThanhTien, 
       tblhoadon.TongTien 
FROM tblhoadon, 
     tblphongtro,
     tbldichvu,
     tblchitietdv 
WHERE tblhoadon.MaKhachHang = tblkhachhang.MaKhachHang AND 
      tblhoadon.MaSoPhong   = tblphongtro.MaSoPhong AND
      tblhoadon.MaDichVu    = tbldichvu.MaDichVu AND
      tbldichvu.MaDichVu    = tblchitietdv.MaDichVu AND
      tblchitiedv.MaDichVu = '10040001'
```

Comment: Missing from your answer: implicit vs explicit joins + tblkhachhang is not in the from clause.